# RoundTripOriginalAttribute not getting orignial value back to the server

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am working with DTOs(Data Transfer Objects) on server.

The scenerio which i am trying to Achieve,
I have a list of Addresses on my PersonDTO object, and if I delete or add new Items to the list of Addresses, I would like to perform some additional implementation on the server. So, for that I am using [RoundTripOriginial], which as in MSDN says that it will return an original object back to server along with the updated object.

Note : I donot want to make a database call to get the original entity.

Here is my sample Structure,

```
[RoundtripOriginal]
Public Class PersonDTO
{

        [Include]
        [Composition]
        [Association("PersonDTO_AddressDTO", "Id", "ReferenceId")]
        public List<Address> Addresses
        { get
            {
                if (addressed== null)
                    addressed= new List<Address>();
                return addressed;
            }
            set { addressed= value; }
        }
}
```

On the DomainService

```
[Update]    
   public void UpdatePersonDTO(PersonDTO person)
    {
      PersonDTO originalPerson =  this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(person); 
    }
```

But, the GetOriginal returns me 'null',

Am I missing something here.

Any sort of suggestion/Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In WCF Ria Services you must put the `RoundTripOriginalAttribute` on your class members, not on the class itself. It's meant to let you round trip properties mainly for concurrency checks server-side.

Comment: When I try to put the Attribute on a collection property which has an association as well. It throws a compile error "Association Members cannot be marked RoundTripOriginal".

Comment: that's correct. it's meant to be used on "primitives" property. Associations can't be "Roundtripped" you should instead put the RoundTripOriginalAttribute on the primitive properties of your association